# Looped .prevAll()?

Tags: jquery, arrays, performance, dom, methods

I am looking for a method, that works similar to jQuery `.prevAll()`:
returns array-like object of DOM nodes in a logical and usable sorting order (based on how many steps back the elements are), but loops through the siblings, and gets the next elements as well. Let's say:

```
<parent>
    <c1 />
    <c2 />
    <c3 />
    <c4 />
    <c5 />
    <c6 />
</parent>
```

I would like to select c3, `$("parent>c3")` and call the looped `.prevAll()`-like function to get an array with these jQuery objects in it:

```
[0] : c2 node
[1] : c1 node
[2] : c6 node
[3] : c5 node
[4] : c4 node
```

How could I achieve this in the fastest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge the result using `prevAll()/nextAll()` methods:

### --DEMO--

```
var $set = $($.merge($(this).prevAll().get(), $(this).nextAll().get().reverse()));
console.log($set);
```